# cant load controller function when clicking tag a on ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have problem with my ajax in CodeIgniter, I cannot load function even I clicks on my anchor tag.

my view :

```
<a id="delete_article" href="#" style="margin-top:0px"><span class="label label-danger">Delete</span></a>
```

my ajax function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#delete_article").click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                 jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/ui_controller/deletearticle/<?php echo $twid;?>/<?php echo $id_session; ?>",
                    success: function(res){
                        $('#list_article').load("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/ui_controller/list_article_plain/<?php echo $uid; ?>");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

my controller :

```
public function deletearticle($twid,$uid){
        $this->ui_model->deletearticle($twid);
}

public function list_article_plain($uid){
        $data['article'] = $this->ui_model->get_a_place_where_uid($uid);
        $this->load->view('user/list_article.html' , $data);
}
```

my model :

```
public function deletearticle($twid){
        $this->db->where('twid', $twid);
        $this->db->delete('tempat_wisata'); 
}
```

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: my base_url looks like 'http://localhost/myfolder'

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: No Ahmad, in your `application/config/routes.php` file - what routes have you set up?

Comment: Why do you pass/require 2 variables to deletearticle controller, when you use only one - $twid?

Comment: Maybe csrf_token is set to true in your config.php file? In that case you need to submit the token for POST requests.

Comment: i was just set $route['default_controller'] to main controller , thats all.

Comment: JavaScript does not care about your server-side code or framework.  Please show us the ***rendered*** JavaScript code as seen by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is executed based on event, while PHP is the first to be executed.
Your 'url' in

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/ui_controller/deletearticle/<?php echo $twid;?>/<?php echo $id_session; ?>",
  success: function(res){
    $('#list_article').load("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/ui_controller/list_article_plain/<?php echo $uid; ?>");
  }
});
```

is invalid.
The server simply do not execute the php code in 'url'.

Comment: Yes, the PHP is executed on the server, so the PHP values are already in place within this block of JavaScript code when the page is created.  To know if the URL is invalid, we'd need to inspect the code as it's rendered in the browser, not the server-side code shown to us by the OP.